# Count wrapped lines in a textbox

Tags: .net, vb.net, textbox

I have a single line of text in a Text Box and that is wrapped to many lines, how to count no of wrapped lines in Text Box?

Comment: Which language in .Net? C#,VB.Net?

Comment: @ShreyasBhat: note that i've edited my answer since it seems that you want to count the visible lines, not the "physical" lines wrapped by line breaks.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `String.Split`:

```
int lineCount = txt.Text.Split(new[] { '\n', 'r' }, StringSplitOptions.None).Length;
```

If it's a winforms `TextBox` you can also use the `Lines` property:

```
int lineCount = txt.Lines.Length;
```

So it's VB.NET:

```
Dim lineCount = txt.Text.Split({vbLf, vbCr}, StringSplitOptions.None).Length
```

**Update**: Maybe my understanding was wrong and you want to count the "lines" that the UI-element (like the `TextBox`) wrapped your single-line text. Then above doesn't work of course.

You could use [`Text.GetLineFromCharIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.getlinefromcharindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Dim lineCount = txt.GetLineFromCharIndex(txt.Text.Length - 1)
```

I must admit that i didnt know `GetLineFromCharIndex` before, but it seems to work as expected. I have entered a long single line text and the linecount was 23. After i've reduced the width of the textbox it has changed to 40.

Comment: @RahulTripathi: added VB

Comment: I see that. Now that makes it complete! +1

Comment: Are you sure?  Did you test this?  The wrap is by the UI element and it does not insert line breaks.

Comment: @Blam: i have edited my answer. I must admit that i didnt know `GetLineFromCharIndex` before, but it seems to work as expected. I have entered a long single line text and the linecount was 23. If i reduce the width of the textbox it changes to 40.