# Get LineCount from a textbox with wrapping

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, textbox

I want to get how many lines of the textbox with wrapping. The following code is not working.

```
void txt_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
       TextBox t = (TextBox)sender;
       var count = t.LinesCount; // wrong;
       // or
       var lineCount = t.Text.Split(new[] {'\n','r'}).length;
}
```

I have three lines, but `var lineCount = t.Text.Split(new[] {'\n','r'}).length;` returns 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that I found the why the `LineCount` is not working.`

The TextBox is actually in the DataColumn. I set a Width as 2*.

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Info" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Info}"  Width="2*">
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox
                            AcceptsReturn="True"
                            TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                            Text="{Binding Info, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                            Loaded="TextBox_Loaded"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
            </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>`.
```

The Width property causes the issue. If I remove it then it works. But I need the width, not sure why and how?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code and are looking for the letter `r` instead of a carriage return `\r`

Try `var lineCount = t.Text.Split(new[] {'\n','\r'}).length;`

Another option would be to split as above and then divide the length of each line by the number of characters you can have on a single line. You may need to calculate this as it doesn't seem like TextBox has a `Columns` property.

Comment: If that it just returns 1 always. It is not the typo, I found it at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30617928/count-wrapped-lines-in-a-textbox

Comment: I would imagine that answer also has a typo as the original question was for VB.Net and the C# solution was never checked. If you check the documentation for String.Split(..), the parameter value `'r'` would simply split your Text property by any appearance of the letter `r`.

Comment: Why don’t you use the System.Environmnet.NewLine like t.Text.Split(
    new[] { Environment.NewLine },
    StringSplitOptions.None
).Length;

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the number of wrapped lines, you can use [GetLineIndexFromCharacterIndex()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textbox.getlineindexfromcharacterindex?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Controls.TextBox.GetLineIndexFromCharacterIndex);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2).
As parameter, you can pass the last character (corresponding to the `Text.Lenght`).

```
int WrappedLines1 = TextBox.GetLineIndexFromCharacterIndex(TextBox.Text.Length) + 1;
```

Or [TextBox.LineCount()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textbox.linecount?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Controls.TextBox.LineCount);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2).
The first method returns a zero-based index, the second starts counting from 1.

```
int WrappedLines2 = TextBox.LineCount;
```

The number of physical line (lines separated by a line feed) can be calculated with `Split().Count()`.

```
int LineFeedsCount = TextBox.Text.Split(new[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None).Count();
```

It you don't want to count empty lines, use  `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` as option parameter.

You can verify that the number of lines is correct, setting the `TextWrapping` property to `.NoWrap` and counting the lines with `.LineCount`.

```
TextBox1.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.NoWrap;
int LineFeedsCount = TextBox1.LineCount;
```